# How can I dynamically re-configure a Service during runtime in ASP.NET Core 5?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am using Google authentication in my web app, and the OAuth keys are currently hard-coded in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddGoogle(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = "my-client-id";
        options.ClientSecret = "my-client-secret";
    });
```

However, I would like to give the site administrator the opportunity to change the ClientId and ClientSecret from the web app's settings page, preferably without having to restart the server.

To do this, I'd have to somehow trigger a re-configuration of the Google service and the GoogleOptions object when the user hits 'Save' on the settings page. This is what I'm having trouble with. Also, I would like to store these settings in an EF Core DbContext, and not in a physical config file.

So far I've tried to move the settings to a separate class that implements IPostConfigureOptions. This should allow me to inject my database context, because based on the documentation, PostConfigure is supposed to run after all other configurations have occurred. The settings are loaded correctly from this new class, but the injection of the DB context fails with the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'AppDatabase' from singleton 'IOptionsMonitor`1[GoogleOptions]'
```

This is weird, because the ConfigureGoogleOptions is registered as Scoped, and not as a Singleton.

Here's my options class:

```
public class ConfigureGoogleOptions : IPostConfigureOptions<GoogleOptions>
{
    private readonly AppDatabase database;

    public ConfigureGoogleOptions(AppDatabase database)
    {
        this.database = database;
    }
    
    public void PostConfigure(string name, GoogleOptions options)
    {
        options.ClientId = "my-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        options.ClientSecret = "my-client-secret";
    }
}
```

And registering it in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddScoped<IPostConfigureOptions<GoogleOptions>, ConfigureGoogleOptions>();
```

Even if the databse injection worked, there's still a second problem. The `PostConfigure` function in my class only gets called once after the application starts, and never again. I assume that it caches the settings somewhere, and I don't know how to invalidate or disable this cache so I can dynamically provide values.

**Short Summary / tl;dr:**

I want to load the ClientId and ClientSecret settings of the Google OAuth service from my own database, and I want to be able to change them dynamically while the server is running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally the google handler will use `IOptionsMonitor<GoogleOptions>` to get the `GoogleOptions` ***once*** or until it's reloaded (such as when the options is bound from a configuration file and saving the file will trigger the reloading). The `IOptionsMonitor` internally will use `IOptionsMonitorCache` and this cache is registered as singleton. So the options instance you get from `IOptionsMonitor<GoogleOptions>` is the same (reference) with the `AuthenticationHandler<GoogleOptions>.Options` which is used for various operations inside the handler. Even other code if using that options should correctly get it from `IOptionsMonitor<GoogleOptions>`.

So to change the options at runtime, it's just simple like this:

```
//inject the IOptionsMonitor<GoogleOptions> into _googleOptionsMonitor;
var runtimeOptions = _googleOptionsMonitor.Get(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
//you change properties of runtimeOptions here
//...
```

The important point here is we need to use `GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` as the key to get the correct instance of options. The `IOptionsMonitor.CurrentValue` will use the default key of `Options.DefaultName` (which is an empty string).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that it is this simple. I assume it would be roughly the same process for `MicrosoftAccountOptions` with `MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`.

Comment: @LázárZsolt yes, it's the same, the `Options` property is declared in the base `AuthenticationHandler<TOptions>`. Actually what I've found out here is by reading the source code, it's not documented anywhere. This kind of design seems to be good and will not be changed anytime soon.

Comment: @KingKing, can we change connection string for DbContext with your method? Tell me how, please?

Comment: @GoodSimon it's required to look into the source code of related code (EFCore) to answer your question . But I guess that your scenario is a bit different and you can change the connection string another way. Looks like you just want to change the connection string based on each specific request (before entering the scope in which the DbContext will be created and used). That's like a scenario called `per-tenant DbContext`. If that's the case, you can change the connection string while building the `DbContextOptions` such as by using the `AddDbContext` accepting a delegate to configure more.

Comment: @KingKing I think it's not (or no longer) possible to update MicrosoftAccountOptions this way as this issue suggests: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/1299

Would be happy to be wrong however, so if you could provide details, it would be highly appreciated.