# External Login with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, openid

I'm developing an authentication system using ASP.NET and I want to enable the client to add an external login like Facebook, Google or whatever; he just needs to enter the required parameters.

My problem is how can I add the authentication handler to the server dynamically after the admin adds it?

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = "YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID";
                options.ClientSecret = "YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET";
            })
            .AddFacebook(options =>
            {
                options.AppId = "YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID";
                options.AppSecret = "YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET";
            });
```

Comment: you'll need to move your snippet into its own class. Dependency inject the configurationService in the constructor and store it in a private field.

You'll need to run each AddX() based on what is in your settings file that contains what user provided from the database. Register this new class in your startup as a singleton.

To allow user to update it, you can inject this new class inside your api controller or api function, update the database to persists data and call the approriate function in new class so service doesnt have to be restarted to apply.

Comment: can you provide me with example

Comment: what do you mean dynamically? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: for example if the admin enable the facebook login the user will be able to use it instantly and if he disable it th user will not be able to login with facebook

Comment: perhaps this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66791061/how-can-i-dynamically-re-configure-a-service-during-runtime-in-asp-net-core-5